# Animations in custom view - android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I am having a little confusion in handling animations when it comes to my custom view. 
What I'm having right now is a class like this:

```
public class ConcreteView extends RelativeLayout {
      //blah blah code
      public ConcreteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          //blah blah code
      }
       //blah blah code
}
```

and an xml like this:

```
<com.package.ConcreteView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/suggest"
    app:headerText="This is a custom view. Animations yet to be implemented"
    app:headertextColor="#212121"
    app:footerText="Frostbite engine"
    app:footertextColor="#424242"
    app:footertextSize="9"
    app:headerTextFontSize="13"/>
```

Now what I'm **looking for** is a way to implement all of the basic animations (like fadeIn, fadeOut, slide In/Out etc.) inside this class (programmatically) so that I just have to make an instance of **ConcreteView** and access the setAnimation method. Any Ideas?

Thanks, 
Shantanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your implementation of the custom view, you can always access the view and the view functions using the **`this`** operator. Using that, you should be able to change the properties of the view as per the animation.

So, it would be something like

```
public class ConcreteView extends RelativeLayout {
      //blah blah code
      public ConcreteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          //blah blah code
      }
       //blah blah code

      public void blahAnimationFadeOut(){
           this.setAlpha(0.5); // dummy example to access all view functions, assuming you can write your own animations programatically
      }
}
```